# In master/slave how to turn on and off certain topics?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For our project, we have a master and a slave network setup. They are publishing and subscribing to each other wirelessly. The camera topic takes up too much bandwidth. Is it possible to turn on and off this topic when we want to view the data on the slave?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283486/in-master/slave-how-to-turn-on-and-off-certain-topics?/) by [ac](https://answers.ros.org/users/33836/ac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The camera topic takes up too much bandwidth. Is it possible to turn on and off this topic when we want to view the data on the slave?

would unsubscribing not be an option?

If you don't subscribe the publisher should not use any network resources.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0